# Reorder list of objects in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view that displays a list of objects. Objects in the list with display 1 are displayed left aligned, while objects with display 2 and parent property 1 are indented under the property 1 object:

```
property1-display1
    property3-display2
    property4-display2
property2-display1
    property5-display2
```

I need to be able to manually change the order of these items within the respective display level using up and down arrow buttons, so if I move `property1-display1` down the both `property3-display2` and `property4-display2` will move down with it. The up and down buttons post back to the controller, but the list is only sent to the database when the user clicks the save button.

I have the code written that does this reording in the controller, but when I try to do a second move the model is back to the original state.

The requirement is that the user can change as many items on the page as needed but none of the changes made to the order of the list should be made until the user clicks the Save button.

I'm at a loss to explain why the model is not updated correctly. I have tried disabling caching for this controller with:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
```

but this made no difference.

The code that reorders the list looks like this:

```
int targetIndex;
var selected = model.ObjectList[index];
var orderNumber = selected.DisplayOrder;
var items =
    model.ObjectList.Where(
        x => x.ParentID == selected.ParentID).ToList();

// if the command is down, get the next lower id number, else get the next highest
switch (direction)
{
    case Constants.MOVE_DOWN:

        var nextDown = items[items.IndexOf(selected) + 1];

        targetIndex = model.ObjectList.IndexOf(nextDown);

        // set the display order for the item to move down.
        model.ObjectList[index].DisplayOrder =
            model.ObjectList[targetIndex].DisplayOrder;

        // set the display order of the item to move up
        model.ObjectList[targetIndex].DisplayOrder =
            orderNumber;

        break;
    case Constants.MOVE_UP:

        var nextUp = items[items.IndexOf(selected) - 1];

        targetIndex = model.ObjectList.IndexOf(nextUp);

        // set the display order for the item to move down.
        model.ObjectList[index].DisplayOrder =
            model.ObjectList[targetIndex].DisplayOrder;

        // set the display order of the item to move up
        model.ObjectList[targetIndex].DisplayOrder =
            model.ObjectList[index].DisplayOrder;

        break;
}

// get all DisplayLevel 2 items
var displayLevelObjects =
    model.ObjectList.Where(x => x.DisplayLevel == 2)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
    .ToList();

// sort the list by DisplayOrder
displayLevelObjects = displayLevelObjects.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();

var ObjectList = new List<PlanComparisonHeaderViewModel>();

// add children
foreach (var item in displayLevelObjects)
{
    var children =
        model.ObjectList.Where(
            x => x.ParentID == item.ID).Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder);

    ObjectList.Add(item);
    ObjectList.AddRange(children);
}

model.ObjectList = ObjectList;

return View(model);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the new order values after the post to the controller? Did you check to see that those are correct?

Comment: @OmriAharon Yes, the first time I change the order in the list the model has the correct values. It's when posting the second time the order is wrong.

Comment: And the second time right as the request reaches the controller, are the values correct or they're already wrong there?

Comment: @OmriAharon The values are already wrong and the list is back to it's original state

Comment: Well if the the values at the model are correct after the first post, and they're wrong on the second post (even without changing anything?) then something must change on the view and we need some more info.

Comment: @OmriAharon My explanation was unclear, sorry. The values in the first postback are not changed, but I have the index and the direction of the change, so I make the change in the controller, then return the view with the updated model, which displays as expected. The next postback has the original model data, with the index of the change in the "new" model but that no longer corresponds to the model in the controller.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the relevant code in the controller ?

Comment: @OmriAharon the code above is pretty much whats in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is actually pretty simple (thanks to my coworker Jason). Just clear the model state:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

and then return the updated model.